# Telethon, how to get messages from chat, but not don't make requests to get user entites

Tags: python, message, telethon

I am using Telethon and I am getting messages from chat, but as I can see in session file - I have a lot off entities added with users(senders, I think). So I get **WaitFloodError**
looks like because a lot of requests to users also.

So, my question is: Is it possible to make history message request of chat but don't make request to sender so I can bypass WaitFloodError a little bit. I need only info about message.

```py
messages = await client.get_messages(entity=my_channel,search=None,offset_id=offset_id,offset_date=None,add_offset=0,limit=limit,max_id=0,min_id=0)
```

I have tried `GetHistoryRequest`, `get_messages` and looked in documentation for some info how to turn off request to sender, but didn't find any information. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, looking at the [client source](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/319db57ccb97177b376eb7947fbd3cf4def9fe72/telethon/client/messages.py#L556), there doesn't seem to be a option not to retrieve those user details.

To prevent the WaitFloodError, there are some options on `get_messages` like `wait_time` which can help:

- `wait_time`, increase this to wait some time between each request.